# How to pass an anonymous inner bean to a bean definition as a constructor dependency using Groovy bean config

Tags: java, spring, grails, groovy

What I'm trying to achieve is the equivalent Groovy DSL spring config of this:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="com.example.SomeBeanWithConstructorArgs">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="com.example.InnerBean">
            <property name="someService" ref="someService"/>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

According to the [docs](https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/03/groovy-bean-configuration-in-spring-framework-4), you would just pass the constructor arguments to the bean defining method invocation inside the top level closure: `beanName(type, constructor-args)  // parens optional`
But what a need to pass is not a value, but a bean definition.

I know I could define the bean to be passed as contructor-arg as a top level, named bean, and then pass it to the other bean by using a ref, like this:

```
myNamedBean(com.example.InnerBean) {
    someService = ref('someService')
}

myBean(com.example.SomeBeanWithConstructorArgs, ref('myNamedBean'))
```

But I really need `com.example.InnerBean` to be an anonymous, inner bean.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same issue. If we cannot make 'InnerBean' to be anonymous, we will have too many beans defined on the top level.